# Getting response with libcurl and initialization

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm following [this example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html) about posting to an http server. I have the following two concerns:

1. I am not sure who is printing the server response to the screen. It must be curl_easy_perform, but I'm not sure how to disable it. I would simply like to know whether I got 200 OK or some other response.
2. In case there are two threads using curl at the same time, do they both need to initialize using curl_easy_init, or is it something that needs to be done once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your answers are answered in the [curl FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html):

> 5.10 [How do I prevent libcurl from writing the response to stdout](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_prevent_libcurl_from_wr)?
>
> libcurl provides a default built-in write function that writes
>   received data to stdout. Set the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to receive the
>   data, or possibly set CURLOPT_WRITEDATA to a different FILE * handle.

and parts of the second answer is found in this question:

> 5.1 [Is libcurl thread-safe?](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Is_libcurl_thread_safe)
>
> Yes.
>
> We have written the libcurl code specifically adjusted for
>   multi-threaded programs. libcurl will use thread-safe functions
>   instead of non-safe ones if your system has such. **Note that you must
>   never share the same handle in multiple threads.**

So basically if you use separate curl handles in separate threads you're fine, but if you use SSL based protocol you should follow the thread-safe link and see what SSL mutex callbacks you need to set!